# Issue in zk validation

Tags: java, zk

I'm using validation with zk input constraints. When clicking the save button, `doSave` is still called, but it should not be.

I want to do when it's trigger, the save operation must be stop.

Another issue is, that zk allows % in `Intbox`.

Here is what I have tried.

validation.zul

```
<zk>
<window width="100%" height="100%"
    apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.test.Validation')">

    <toolbar id="listToolbarProcess" sclass="vista" height="20px"
        align="start">

        <toolbarbutton label="Save" onClick="@command('doSave')" ></toolbarbutton>

    </toolbar>

    <vlayout sclass="vertical-scroll" vflex="1">

        <intbox id="priority" value="@bind(vm.value)" maxlength="3"
            constraint="no empty" ></intbox>
            <datebox value="@bind(vm.date)"></datebox>
    </vlayout>

</window>
```

Validation.java

```
 package com.test;

 import java.sql.Timestamp;

 import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.AfterCompose;
  import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
   import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
   import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
   import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;

  public class Validation {

/**
 * @author Himanshu
 */
Integer value;

public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Integer value) {
    this.value = value;
}
    Timestamp date;
public Timestamp getDate() {
return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
this.date = date;
     }

@AfterCompose
public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {

}

@Command
public void doSave() {

    System.out.println(" value =" + value);
    System.out.println(" Date Value =" + date);
}

}
```

Thanks
Himanshu

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/Validator) part of zk doc. It explains how to avoid 
the calling of databinding methods if validation fails.

If you want your input to (not) accept `%`, use a [textbox with regex](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Input/Textbox).
If you want to mask your input, [look here](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/effects/form_effect).

Comment: zk validate % and show validation message but my issue is user should enter % inside Intbox just like character or any other. intbox only allows integer value.

Comment: The awnser is the same. Use a Textbox with regex, so you can define everything you want.

Comment: Hi Nabil ZK dose not support this type of validation http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/pprAjaxValidations.jsf

Comment: i want user enter only integer. please test the intbox user cannot enter text but enter % and integer.my Question is user should not enter % just like text. intbox must be disable for %.

Comment: I added a zk demo where you can see how to mask the input, if that is what you want.

Comment: Nabil i think you did not get @Kabuni point as he mentioned that he is able to enter '%' in the intbox,this is not look like a bug ? how can a person can enter % in intbox? is their any meaning here to insert % in intbox?

Comment: I do not think this is a bug, cos if you may want to have a % or absulute input you like to have just numbers and %. But a textbox with a regex constraint or a mask will do it no metter if you want or don't want % in you input.

Comment: From my understanding then ZK team can add a attribute in intbox something like this prefix="$" or prefix="%" etc. its look much easy otherwise everyone have to add extra validation to prevent user to insert %.